# What form of "log" saving does this site use?

Tags: php, ip

My question is about this site, http://psncardgenerator.com/ . As you can see every user has their own link on the site. If you refresh the page, the link remains the same. I have checked that http://psncardgenerator.com/ doesnt use cookies or sessions to save the link for the visitor. Does anyone know how they do it?

Comment: I've got cookies on that site when I visit it. Domain .addthis.com and path /

Comment: the addthis cookie isnt from the site, its from a widget on the site.

Comment: Duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738943/how-to-copy-these-php-elements).

Answer (score 1):

Since you already listed [ip](/questions/tagged/ip) in your question, yes, that is how they most likely do it.

It's as simple as keeping the last accessed REMOTE_ADDR in a database table, and associating the random `?i=123456` id with it. It's no different than your typical user counter.

---

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
$userid = db("SELECT userid FROM userids WHERE ip=?", $ip)->userid;

if (!$userid) {
   db("INSERT INTO userids (ip, userid) VALUES (?,?)", $ip, 0);
   # and then select it again...
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how this would look like in a script?

Comment: You have a table - id (auto-incrementing) and ip. `SELECT` from your table, finding out if an ip is there matching the user's IP ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']). If no match is found, proceed to `INSERT` the user's ip into the table. After that or when a match is found, display the id associated with the user's ip.

Comment: is the script above a php script?

Comment: Yes, but obviously the db() function is not standard. You would use the more fiddly mysql_query function instead. And also this should be restructured. -- Anyway, I guess you might find a complete script by searching for "php user counter". They usually keep just such numeric indicies.